# Storing array in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

i was looking through SO and following several indications but i still stucked on this.

Im trying to store an array in interest_id column.

Here's mi code and the traceback, it seems trying to saving a hash instead an array, the question is why?

**migration:**

```
class CreateSearches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :searches do |t|
      t.integer :occasion_id
      t.integer :relationship_id
      t.integer :target_id
      t.integer :genre_id
      t.text :interest_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**model:**

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :interest_id, Array
  def search_products
    products = Product.all
    products = Product.joins(:occasion_products).where(:occasion_products => {:occasion_id => occasion_id}) if occasion_id.present?
    products = Product.joins(:relationship_products).where(:relationship_products => {:relationship_id => relationship_id}) if relationship_id.present?
    products = Product.joins(:genre_products).where(:genre_products => {:genre_id => genre_id}) if genre_id.present?
    products = Product.joins(:target_products).where(:target_products => {:target_id => target_id}) if target_id.present?
    products = Product.joins(:interest_products).where(:interest_products => {:interest_id => interest_id}) if interest_id.present?
    return products
  end
end
```

**controller:**

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end
  def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end
  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end

  private   
  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:occasion_id, :relationship_id, :genre_id, :target_id, {:interest_id => []})
  end
end
```

**traceback:**

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch in SearchesController#create
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a Fixnum. -- 0
Extracted source (around line #6):

4
5
6
7
8
9




  end
  def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end
  def show

Rails.root: /Users/emadobao/Sites/rails/personalgifter
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:6:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"4mS9gQN8g/DWFab+Ecz77o2FTyGIY7/EezzCGXjkbIdmT4srMsixbFDEg25bgdVaOTuIUJRDedcKudYvPCDLgw==",
 "search"=>{"occasion_id"=>"1",
 "relationship_id"=>"1",
 "target_id"=>"1",
 "genre_id"=>"1",
 "interest_id"=>["",
 "2",
 "4"]},
 "commit"=>"Search"}

Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None

x
>>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but ActiveRecord may not handle column names ending with `_id` well unless they are integers (and foreign keys). I'd recommend choosing a different name, one other than `interest_id` for the aforementioned reason and also because the name is not accurately descriptive of the column contents. Maybe pluralizing the name to `interest_ids` makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be approaching the problem wrong from the start. Sure it's technically possible to hack ActiveRecord to shove a list of ids into a text column - but it's not the Rails Way (or even a very good way).

Instead you would define the relationship as:

```
class Search
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searches
end
```

Note that you can't really store a many to many relationship on a single table - you can't store all the related products ids on the `searches` table even if that seems like a good solution*. That's just not how relational databases work.

For this to work you need to create a join table:

```
rails g migration CreateProductsSearchesJoinTable products searches  
rake db:migrate
```

Which creates a join table like this:

```
create_table "products_searches", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "product_id", null: false
  t.integer "search_id",  null: false
end
```

Then you can assign products by:

```
@search.products << Product.where(foo: "bar")
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: * it is possible to use a string or an array type. Its just a bad idea since you lose the ability to use foreign keys to guarantee referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @max and @Wizard of Ogz for your approuchs. Finally i found a solution looking deeper into my code.

I just create a new model InterestSearch and i have modified Search and Intersest models. Here's the final models code:

```
class InterestSearch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :interest
  belongs_to :search
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interest_searches
  has_many :searches, :through => :interest_searches
end

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interest_searches
  has_many :interests, :through => :interest_searches
  serialize :interest_id, Array
  def search_products
    products = Product.all
    products = products.joins(:occasion_products).where(:occasion_products => {:occasion_id => occasion_id}) if occasion_id.present?
    products = products.joins(:relationship_products).where(:relationship_products => {:relationship_id => relationship_id}) if relationship_id.present?
    products = products.joins(:genre_products).where(:genre_products => {:genre_id => genre_id}) if genre_id.present?
    products = products.joins(:target_products).where(:target_products => {:target_id => target_id}) if target_id.present?
    products = products.joins(:interest_products).where(:interest_products => {:interest_id => interest_ids}) if interest_ids.present?
    return products
  end
end
```